# Assigning a value only if certain conditions are fulfilled in Scheme

Tags: scheme, guile

I have a list which may contain some null values. However, I intend to ignore those null values. Example of my list would be:
 `(() () MC+ () MD- () () ME+)`

In my procedure I am iterating over these elements and using let I am creating a local binding variable which binds to one element in this list. However, I should be able to bind the variable only if the value is not null. Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
(let* ([disjunct (car disjunct-list)])
```

However, disjunct should be assigned a value only if that element is not null. This means that the value assigned to disjunct should be: `MC+`

It should iterate over all the values and select the next non-null value and assign it to `disjunct`.

One more thing, I am doing further operations on `disjunct` down the line. And recursively, I am passing the remainder of the list down the line. So the next time I recursively call this procedure, `disjunct` should have the value `MD-`. That is using `(cdr disjunct-list)` I should be able to get the following list: `(() MD- () () ME+)`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Filter the input list from the beginning (before actually passing it to the recursive procedure), so you can safely ignore those pesky empty lists and focus only on the actual values. For example:

```
(define disjuncts (filter (lambda (e) (not (null? e)))
                          '(() () MC+ () MD- () () ME+)))
(car disjuncts)
=> 'MC+

(cadr disjuncts)
=> 'MD-

(caddr disjuncts)
=> 'ME+
```

Comment: That is the way to go. I agree. But is there a way to do what I asked above. I have already implemented a filter. I was curious if there was a way to do what I have outlined above.

Comment: @RohitShinde you'd have to take the `car` of each element and ask if it's `null?` before using it. A real hassle if you ask me, it'll be much cleaner if we guarantee that the input data is alright before processing it ;)